# "Recapturing" escape characters

Tags: c#

In c#, how could I turn literally `"\\b"` into literally `"\b"`, assuming I did not know the last character, the characters after or if there were any characters in front of the escaped ones, or multiple escaped characters?

Comment: What about Unicode escape sequences, which have multiple characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your exact requirements, but to get `"\\b"` down to `"\b"` you could try using Regex Unescape.

```
var foo = @"\\b"; //The @ is important if you wish to keep things literal 
var bar = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without knowing the characters that occur before "\b".

In this particular case, this string will be parsed as `"\b"` because the escape sequence `'\\'` is read as `'\'`.

However, if there were another `"\"` preceeding `"\\b"`, you would get a different result.

For example, `"\\\b"` would be parsed as two characters: `"\"` and `"\b"`.

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you are not familiar with verbatim string literals in C#, you might want to look them up.  You can mark a string literal as a verbatim string literal by prefacing it with an @ sign.  This tells the compiler to ignore the escape sequences (except for doublequotes) and parse the string exactly as is.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple String.Replace should be enough:

```
var source = @"foo\\bbar";
var result = source.Replace(@"\\b", @"\b")
```

If you don't know "b" part - use regular expression version of [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that allows you to check for match itself :

```
var result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\\\\.", 
       match => match.Value .Substring(1))
```

Comment: Your regex is close, although I have to use the long-hand method for various reasons.. `encoded = Regex.Replace(encoded, @"\\.", delegate(Match m) { return m.Value.Substring(1); });` is very close as it removes the double escape, but a single slash is not replaced. 
With  `@"\\\\."` either no match is found or it is found and replaced with a double escape (i.e. it doesn't change)